# When printing PDF Document from Java, some of the text is rotated

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I tried to print a PDF document from Java using PDFRenderer and ICEpdf.
In both cases some of the text came out rotated in 180 degrees while the images stayed correct.
With PDFREndere all the text is rotated and in ICEpdf only some of the lines.
Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Does the PDF show up okay in other PDF viewers (Acrobat, Ghostscript, Evince, Fox...)? Does it only happen when printing?

Comment: In Acrobat the document shows OK and printed well.
In PDFRenderer the text is rotated also when I display the data in the PagePanel.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in pdf renderer. Have you tried their bug tracker? https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectIssues

Comment: Yes. I openned a bug.
I solved the problem by using a different PDF library.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the font you are using in the document isn't available on the system. I had the very same problem with java-generated eps files.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the pdf is broken. Also try to open the pdf using Ghostscript. Acrobat is too indulgent with broken or malformed pdf files (it automatically correct some "syntax" error in the pdf structure).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced exact same issue when text came out rotated in 180 degrees while the images stayed correct in the PDF file.
I have fixed the issue after adding below code snippet:

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream();
if (page.getRotation() == 180) {
    //rotate the text according to the page rotation
    contentStream.setTextMatrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 580, 15*1.5);
 }
```